# colocar una lista al lado de otra y alinearlas

Tags: html, css

No soy muy amiga de `css`v y tengo un `div` con dos `ul` y quiero que estén una al lado de la otra y que queden alineadas pero me queda una por milímetros mas baja que la otra.

Las puse al lado con un `float left` y probé agregarle un `align-items center` pero no funciona.

Muestro el código:

```css
.contact ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20%;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div className='contact'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h4>Contactanos</h4>
    </li>
    <li><i class="bi bi-telephone"></i> Llamar: 077 009 0046</li>
    <li><i class="bi bi-envelope"></i> Email: info@vanilla.com.ar</li>
    <li><i class="bi bi-geo-alt"></i><a href='https://www.oca.com.ar/Busquedas/Envios' target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"> Segui tu orden</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h4>Horarios de atencion:</h4>
    </li>
    <li>Lunes-Viernes: 8:00AM-10:00PM</li>
    <li>Sabados: 9:00AM-3:00AM</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tendrías que ingresar solamente a la clase `contact` y hacer flexible a los `ul` de adentro para que estén uno al lado del otro, así:

```
.contact {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 50px;
}
```

En donde:

- `display: flex;`: Hago flexible al contenido de adentro para que estén uno al lado del otro.
- `justify-content: center;`: Justifico (posiciono) a los elementos al centro.
- `gap: 50px;`: Hago una separación de `50px` entre los elementos.

---

Código completo:

```css
.contact {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='contact'>
  <ul>
    <li><h4>Contactanos</h4></li>
    <li><i class="bi bi-telephone"></i> Llamar: 077 009 0046</li>
    <li><i class="bi bi-envelope"></i> Email: info@vanilla.com.ar</li>
    <li><i class="bi bi-geo-alt"></i><a href='https://www.oca.com.ar/Busquedas/Envios' target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"> Segui tu orden</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><h4>Horarios de atencion:</h4></li>
    <li>Lunes-Viernes: 8:00AM-10:00PM</li>
    <li>Sabados: 9:00AM-3:00AM</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

className es class

ese es el problema

```css
.contact {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.contact ul {
  max-width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class='contact'>
        <ul>
          <li><h4>Contactanos</h4></li>
          <li><i class="bi bi-telephone"></i> Llamar: 077 009 0046</li>
          <li><i class="bi bi-envelope"></i> Email: info@vanilla.com.ar</li>
          <li><i class="bi bi-geo-alt"></i><a href='https://www.oca.com.ar/Busquedas/Envios' target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"> Segui tu orden</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li><h4>Horarios de atencion:</h4></li>
          <li>Lunes-Viernes: 8:00AM-10:00PM</li>
          <li>Sabados: 9:00AM-3:00AM</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: No, className no es el problema, es un atributo común en react https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html. El problema era en los estilos (que por cierto, se te olvidó explicar).